# SQL INNER JOIN not working from PHP application to take data from progress database

Tags: php, sql, openedge, progress-db

any help appreciated, first time trying this.

My SQL INNER JOIN not working from PHP application to take data from progress database.

My code for the SQL query is:

```
$sql="SELECT * from pub.table1 inner join pub.table2 on table1.nsnref = table2.nrnref where table1.nsscac <> '' and table1.client = 'tgl' and table2.nrname matches '*" .$_POST['suggest']. "*'";
```

The table names have been changed to protect the innocent. If I run any SQL query without a join it returns through ajax call very quickly, but joins not working for me :(

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Don't blame the join.

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean? Please provide a specific answer

Comment: does not look like a correct statement.. `SELECT * FROM table1 A JOIN table2 B ON A.nsnref = B.nsnref...`

Comment: Hi @Odyssey1111 if I run an equivalent statement into the progress editor directly it works fine, the pub.table1 is required to connect to the table through my ODBC connection

Comment: `SELECT * from pub.table1` stands for select * from table1 in database pub you should use it in your join as well if you want to specify the db in the query. `join pub.table2 on pub.table1.nsnref = pub.table2.nrnref`

Comment: @Odyssey1111 thanks for the explanation and response, that wasn't the issue it was an issue with mixing up my languages, but thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you set the table's alias: `pub.table1` is not correct; `pub AS table1` OR `pub table1` is correct

```
SELECT * 
   FROM pub table1 
  INNER JOIN pub table2 ON table1.nsnref = table2.nrnref 
   WHERE table1.nsscac <> '' AND 
     table1.client = 'tgl' AND 
     table2.nrname matches '*" .$_POST['suggest']. "*'"
```

If the pub is the database then set another alias for the table

```
SELECT * 
   FROM pub.table1 T1
  INNER JOIN pub.table2 T2 ON T1.nsnref = T2.nrnref 
   WHERE T1.nsscac <> '' AND 
     T1.client = 'tgl' AND 
     T2.nrname matches '*" .$_POST['suggest']. "*'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrgh! Fixed the issue, was using Progress 'matches' keyword when I should have been using sql 'like' keyword. My own fault. Thanks to @danielpopa for trying to help.

Comment: Kindly. Match .. Against or REGEXP if LIKE doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks again @danielpopa